# Schema in crate

Tags: schema, partitioning, crate

I have a requirement like keep two tables with same name in crate, In mysql we can achieve it using different schema. Any solution like this in crate?

I saw information schema and partitioned table in crate but that not helping me in this case.

Comment: Apparently [not](https://crate.io/docs/stable/sql/reference/create_table.html): "Setting a schema (for example, CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable ...) is currently not supprted *(sic)*. All userspace defined data tables are defined under the default schema named doc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually the current testing release 0.46.0 contains support for schemas! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crateio/YbYqUQ5iOAc